# Identityserver4 is single sign on not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I want to achieve single sign on functionality for different apps so that if i log in into one app then i can go to other app without logging in again.
There are two client apps App1 and App2 which are running locally and identity server 4 app which is running on http://identity.colaraz.net/Account/Login:

App1 is mvc core app which uses code flow
App2 is web forms app which uses Implicit flow

Test Case 1 (Not working) : 
If I sign in into app1 and tries to go to app2 on same browser's new window then I am not able to go to app2 rather I am redirected again to log_in page. [Facing issue in this approach]

Test Case 2 (Working fine) : 
                      If i sign in into app2 and try to go to app1 on same browser's new window then I am able to go to app1 and found myself log in also in app1. [Done as required]
Now how to achieve same functionality for vice versa.

Comment: hi! how do you go to the second app in each combination? manually opening the window, clicking on hyperlink, something other? anyway you app must perform a http redirect to your identity. you have to compare that requests in working and not cases. when authenticated by idsrv, there must be session cookies, otherwise it will ask to login.

Comment: i open the second app by manually opening a new window. I should tell you when i use implicit flow in both apps then i am able to achieve desired functionality. One other thing is that i am unable to achieve single log out functionality in any case

Comment: you have to compare your traffic (through the dev console in browser) in both cases when you opening each second app. the answer must be there.

Comment: hi d_f i have compared traffic but i am unable to found any helpful thing there except that if user is being logged in also into the second app then i can see in network he is redirected to second app call back function but if he is not redirected to second app rather he is redirected to login page then i can see in network that that he is being redirected to login page rather than second app call back

Comment: the key values in the traffic are headers, namely the cookies. I asked you to compare the requests (when redirected) to identityserver in the "good" and "bad" cases.